# The pyspark groupby generates multiple rows in output with String groupby key

Tags: sql, pyspark

The pyspark groupby operation does not produce unique group keys for large data sets

I see repeated keys in the final output.

```
 new_df = df.select('key','value') \
        .where(...) \
        .groupBy('key') \
        .count()
```

e.g. above query returns multiple rows for a groupBy column (key). The datatype for groupby column('key') is string.

I'm storing output in CSV by doing

```
new_df.write.format("csv") \
        .option("header", "true") \
        .mode("Overwrite") \
        .save(CSV_LOCAL_PATH)
```

e.g. output in CSV has duplicate rows

```
key1, 10
key2, 20
key1, 05
```

Tested in Spark 2.4.3 and 2.3
There are duplicates. There is no difference in keys. This happens for multiple KEYS.

It gives 1, when I count the rows for particular keys.

```
new_df.select('key','total')\
 .where((col("key") == "key1"))\
 .count()
```

I'm not sure if pyarrow settings make any difference. I'd it enabled before. I tried with both enabling and disabling pyarrow but the same result.

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")

Comment: The expected output should be a single groupby key.. but that's isn't always true.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not some kind of weird non printable unicode which keeps them separated?

Comment: I've verified and don't see any issues with unicode characters..

Comment: Doing group by multiple times gives the same result (multiple rows with repeating keys)..

Doing following query shows only one row

```
df.select('key','count') \
   .where((col("key") == "key1"))\
   .show()
```

Comment: You mean this is the output of `new_df.select(...`? How did you get the output you have posted in your question?

Comment: I am storing it in csv using below command and I see duplicate rows in CSV file

new_df.write.format("csv") \
        .option("header", "true") \
        .mode("Overwrite") \
        .save(location)

Comment: yes.. I mean `new_df,select` in earlier comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was while saving to the CSV which ignores whitespaces. 
Adding below options helps to resolve it.

```
 .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "false")\
 .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "false")
```